# Duplicate records but except one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table_1

```
ID  Seller  buyer   cost
100 abc     xyz     10.00
200 abc     xyz     10.00
300 abc     xyz     30.00
```

My goal to get select duplicate records and expect result

```
ID  Seller  buyer   cost
100 abc     xyz     10.00
200 abc     xyz     10.00
```

Query

```
select *
from Table_1 
where cost in (
    select cost
    from Table_1
    where seller = buyer
    group by cost
    having count(*) >= 2
)
```

This does not return any results.

Comment: You don't think you got the correct results? Why are you unsure if they are correct or not?

Comment: `where seller = buyer`; there are no rows in your sample data where this is true.

Comment: Return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this

```
select *
from Table_1 t1
where exists (
  select 1
  from Table_1 t2
  where t2.Seller = t1.Seller and t2.Buyer = t1.Buyer and t2.Cost = t1.Cost
  and t1.Id <> t2.Id
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from Table_2 
where cost in (
    select cost
    from Table_2
    group by cost
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: And javascript snippets don't work with SQL.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35123555)