# INSERT INTO / SELECT except if matching values in certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have:

Table A - structure can not be modified:

```
autokey | value1a | value2a | value3a | value4a
```

Table B - no key:

```
value1b | value2b | value3b | value4b
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    SELECT value1b, NULL AS value2b, 111 AS value3b, value4a AS value4b
    FROM TableB 
    WHERE value1b IS NOT NULL
```

Which works fine but because there is no unique key means that it will duplicate everything except the autoinc key. I want however,

- if value1a = value1b, value3a = value3b and value4a = value4b, then don't insert
- if value1a = value1b, value3a = value3b and value4a != value4b then DO insert

Right now I just delete everything with 111 as value3b and reinsert it all to resolve the duplicates. However I now have a need to keep more than 1 value4b

Comment: So what are you stuck on? Sounds like a simple `where not exists`? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77197871/1127428

Comment: What do you do if only one or two values match? And what's wrong with `where not exists`

Comment: Database systems tend to be set-based. Have you looked into [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)?

Comment: You should probably attach some test data in form of tables, so it's possible to understand what you want and not want to insert. But yes, where not exists is usually your friend in these situations

Comment: I've never used where not exists, post an answer and example and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether to insert rows which do not exist at all at TableA or not. This is the only possible condition:

> if value1a = value1b, value3a = value3b and value4a != value4b then DO
> insert

*I also used flat column names because the logic wasn't completely clear, and the sample query isn't valid (Column value4a doesn't exist in TableB)

This can be implemented with:

1. EXISTS (or NOT exists):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    SELECT value1b, value2b, value3b, value4b
    FROM TableB 
    WHERE value1b IS NOT NULL
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM TableA TA2
            WHERE 
                TA2.value1a = TableB.value1b
                AND TA2.value3a = TableB.value3b
                AND TA2.value4a <> TableB.value4b
        )
```

2. JOIN *behaves differently and is probably not good for your case because of One-to-Many relations between the tables.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    SELECT value1b, value2b, value3b, value4b
    FROM TableB 
    JOIN TableA TA2 ON 
        TA2.value1a = TableB.value1b
        AND TA2.value3a = TableB.value3b
        AND TA2.value4a <> TableB.value4b
    WHERE value1b IS NOT NULL
```

3. MERGE which is probably best practice and allows handling different cases to INSERT\UPDATE\DELETE rows from the target table. Removing the extra condition under "WHEN NOT MATCHED" will allow inserting rows that did not match at all.

```
MERGE TableA AS TGT
USING TableB AS SRC 
ON TGT.value1a = SRC.value1b
        AND TGT.value3a = SRC.value3b
        AND TGT.value4a = SRC.value4b
        AND SRC.value1b IS NOT NULL
--WHEN MATCHED THEN... --If necessary
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    AND TGT.value3a = SRC.value3b
    AND TGT.value4a = SRC.value4b
    THEN 
    INSERT (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    VALUES (value1b, value2b, value3b, value4b);
```

Edit for another answer:

> I need whatever is in 4b put into 4a. If 1b, 2b, 3b don't exist in TableA the row needs inserted. Does your option 1 accomplish this?

With a slight modification it will. NOT EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    SELECT value1b, value2b, value3b, value4b
    FROM TableB 
    WHERE value1b IS NOT NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM TableA TA2
            WHERE 
                TA2.value1a = TableB.value1b
                AND TA2.value3a = TableB.value3b
                AND TA2.value4a = TableB.value4b
        )
```

Which is equal to Option 3, when removing the extra conditions.

```
MERGE TableA AS TGT
USING TableB AS SRC 
ON TGT.value1a = SRC.value1b
        AND TGT.value3a = SRC.value3b
        AND TGT.value4a = SRC.value4b
        AND SRC.value1b IS NOT NULL
--WHEN MATCHED THEN... --If necessary
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT (value1a, value2a, value3a, value4a)
    VALUES (value1b, value2b, value3b, value4b);
```

Comment: Thanks! For your questions, I need whatever is in 4b put into 4a. If 1b, 2b, 3b don't exist in TableA the row needs inserted. Does your option 1 accomplish this?

Comment: Option 1 will currently not, because it is looking for existence of 1b,3b. 
With a slight modification it will. 
Which is equal to Option 3, when removing the extra conditions.
I Added the additional code snippets to the original answer.